# Else statement only execute 1 time inside a loop Python

Tags: python

I've got this code

```
def filtraValoraciones (nomFichero = "valoraciones.data"):
# Se crea el archivo de salida
crearArchivoValoracionesFiltradas()
contadorLineasTotal = 0
contadorLineasValidas = 0
lineas = [(l.strip()).split("\t") for l in (open(nomFichero).readlines())]
for l in lineas:
    contadorLineasTotal = contadorLineasTotal + 1
    # Se lee Usuario, Restaurante, Precio y Calidad
    idUsuari = int(l[0])
    idRestaurant = int(l[1])
    precio = round(float(l[2]),2)
    calidad = round(float(l[3]),2)
    if (idUsuari >= 0 and idUsuari <= 99) and (idRestaurant >= 0 and idRestaurant <= 49) and precio > 0.00 and (calidad >= 0.0 and calidad <= 10.00):
        # Tiene valores coherentes --> se vuelcan a otro fichero
        cadena = str(idUsuari) + "    " + str(idRestaurant) + "    " + str(precio) + "    " + str(calidad) + "\n"
        salida = open('valoracionesFiltradas.data','a')
        salida.write (cadena);
        salida.close()
        contadorLineasValidas = contadorLineasValidas + 1
    else:
        cadena2 = str(idUsuari) + "    " + str(idRestaurant) + "    " + str(precio) + "    " + str(calidad) + "\n"
        print cadena2

print "El numero de valoraciones filtradas han sido: " + str(contadorLineasTotal-contadorLineasValidas)
```

When I execute this, If statemente works correctly for lineas.len, but else statement seems to be executed 1 time instead of (contadorLineasTotal-contadorLineasValidas) times.

What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the input file, we have no way of knowing whether the `else` branch should be taken more than once. However, given the indentation problems pointed out by others, it's likely that sth has the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` line is indented with spaces while the `if` line is indented with tabs. Probably the two indentations don't match up from Pythons point of view, so that the `else` doesn't match that `if`. Probably it is on the same indentation as the `for` ([which can also have an `else` block](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)).

Use consistent indentation to avoid such problems. You can also run python with the `-t` flag to get a warning when indentation with both tabs and spaces is used.